# How can I send objects to Spring by GET request?

Tags: java, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3 and I want to make an AJAX call sending an array of objects to a controller. I want my Java to look like this:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/data/save/faults" method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void saveFaultsGET
(
    @RequestParam ("faults") FaultType[] types
) { }
```

Note the `FaultType` is an object I wrote. I am using jQuery and I am not sure how I would format my request URL to achieve this. It would also be helpful to know if it's not possible.

**EDIT** `FaultType` looks like this (getters and setters omitted):

```
public class FaultType {
    private String m_type;
    private boolean m_isTrip;
    private boolean m_isRelay;
    private boolean m_isNonRelay;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very good intro : http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

The ajax call should look something like this:

```
<c:url var="myURL" value="/data/save/faults" />
...
jq.ajax({
  cache:false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: "${myURL}",
  data:jsonFaultType,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success:  function(data) {            
    // yourFunction to call on success eg:
    alert(data);
}
});
```

Your controller signature should look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/data/save/faults" method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String create(@RequestBody FaultType faultType){
...
}
```

Why do you want to send objects using a get request, POST is the defacto method for *posting data to server*. Also, you don't have to return a responsebody, you can also return a **modelAndView**.

Comment: I am using GET requests because it's working for me and I know why it works.